# How to exclude non-single items from two lists?

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I use a stream from two lists to get a list of unique entities?
Match only by username

```
public class Entity {   
    private String username;
    private String password;
}

    var first = Arrays.asList(
            new Entity("user1", ""),
            new Entity("user2", "")
            new Entity("user3", "pass3"),
            new Entity("user5", "pass5")
            
    );

    var second = Arrays.asList(
            new Entity("user1", "pass1"),
            new Entity("user2", "pass2"),
 
    );

    public static void foo(List<Entity> first, List<Entity> second) {
      List<Entity>result = Stream.of(first, second)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            ? 
            ?
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
      }
```

result must be list with Entity("user3", "pass3") and Entity("user5", "pass5")

Comment: Why do you include a Stream construction in your code? That seems like the worst implementation approach for this.

Comment: @daniu could you elaborate on your statement? why is using streams here is a bad approach?

Comment: @SergeiTonoian I need to retract it partially, but I'll give my reasoning. The thing about this is that you need two passes to do this - create a map, then filter it (I didn't think of SergeyAfinogenov's solution). That's not a natural thing to do in a (single) stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can make grouping by username:

```
var groupedData = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getUsername));
```

and then filtered entity which size > 1:

```
groupedData.values().stream()
            .filter(s -> s.size() == 1)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or only one a big stream:

```
Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getUsername)).values().stream()
                .filter(s -> s.size() == 1)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think this is a nice approach

Answer (score 3):

Along with using *groupingBy* you can also use *Collectors.toMap* with merging *(val1, val2) -> null* to exclude elements getting to merge thus leaving only single elements:

```
List<Entity> result = Stream.concat(first.stream(), second.stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entity::getUsername, 
                                                      val -> val, (val1, val2) -> null))
                            .values().stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That feels hacky, but is kind of ingenious (and works).

Comment: Thanx @daniu, I tried to use all approaches

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not the best way

```
 public static List<Entity> foo(List<Entity> first, List<Entity> second) {
    List<Entity> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.addAll(first);
    arr.addAll(second);
    return arr
            .stream()
            .filter(entity -> (first.stream().map(Entity::getUsername).anyMatch(username -> username.equals(entity.getUsername())) &&
                    second.stream().map(Entity::getUsername).noneMatch(username -> username.equals(entity.getUsername()))) ||
                    (second.stream().map(Entity::getUsername).anyMatch(username -> username.equals(entity.getUsername())) &&
                            first.stream().map(Entity::getUsername).noneMatch(username -> username.equals(entity.getUsername()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The logic in the filter is "Exclusive OR", as we don't have a straight way of doing that, we need to make the logic of (Condition1 and not Condition2) or (Condition2 and not Condition1).

Answer (score 0):

*lambda as a straight forward solution*
concat the streams of first-list-entities not contained in second-list and vice versa

```
List<Entity> unique = Stream.concat(
    first.stream().filter(e -> ! second.contains( e )),
    second.stream().filter(e -> ! first.contains( e )) ).collect( toList() );
```